# %27 value in transferring data to another php page

Tags: php, mysql, get

http://127.0.0.1:8888/degis2.php?isim=%27oteller%27&Id=%271%27&oname=%27asasdasfda123445%27

any idea why there is %27 in every variable?

MY code is

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="degis2.php?isim='<?php echo $isim;?>'&Id='<?php echo $id;?>'&oname='<?php echo $name;?>'">
```

Php codes are working as you can see it fills them in the link but probably because of the "%27" it can not find the values in database and return me query failed.

```
$isim=$_GET["isim"];
$id=$_GET["Id"];
$tname=$_GET["oname"];
$name=$_POST["name1"];
$aciklama=$_POST["aciklama1"];
$link=$_POST["link1"];
```

and these are the variables i need. Can anybody help me to clean the %27 value from the link?
Have a nice day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be (without ' after =):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="degis2.php?isim=<?php echo $isim;?>&Id=<?php echo $id;?>&oname=<?php echo $name;?>">
```

Answer (score 3):

`%27` is url-encoded `'`. If you don't need them - remove `'` from your `action`. You don't really need it there, as anything you pass through `get` treated as a string.

Answer (score 3):

`%27` is single quote

```
echo urldecode('%27');
```

and is come from here

```
?isim='<?php echo $isim;?>'&Id='<?php echo $id;?>'&etc...
```

get rid of the single quote in your action attribute should work for you

Answer (score 2):

It is single quote. Learn something about [URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp).